# Can't upgrade Dropbox on headless Ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, dropbox, ubuntu-14.04

Every time I run `dropbox update` I get the following error. Yeah, no idea what that means.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1436, in <module>
    ret = main(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 1425, in main
    result = commands[argv[i]](argv[i+1:])
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 845, in update
    download()
  File "/usr/bin/dropbox", line 586, in download
    get_download_debug_info(download.url, ex))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ex' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: What version of dropbox?  Can the version be upgraded?

Comment: I'm not sure what version number, but it's an older one (I actually got an email from Dropbox warning met o update it before it lost support). I get to that error after typing in `dropbox upgrade`, it looking and finding an update, downloading it, and then attempting to install. During the installation process that happens and it fails.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if Python is having problems then.  You may also try blowing out the install and starting fresh.

Comment: I actually tried that, but I'm a Linux newbie and I failed to do that. Do you know where I could find an idiot's guide to uninstalling Dropbox on an Ubuntu 14.04 headless server?

Comment: Depends.  Are you comfortable with Linux CLI?  If so, something like this should do the trick - https://www.dropbox.com/help/41

Comment: I am, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows:

(Note, you might have dropbox installed in various ways, it can be installed as a package `nautilus-dropbox` or in your home directory at `~/.dropbox-dist` and possibly both which is confusing.)

1. Uninstall all dropbox installations:

   - If you've got the package `nautilus-dropbox` installed then uninstall it: `sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox` and check there's nothing left in `/var/lib/dropbox`
   - Follow the steps to uninstall (click "Linux" in the top right of [this page](https://www.dropbox.com/help/41)) which is basically
     `sudo apt-get remove dropbox; rm -rvf ~/.dropbox ~/.dropbox-dist` (avoid deleting your actual files from `~/Dropbox`)
2. Install latest version:

   - Follow steps [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) (under "Install Dropbox via command line") to install it in your home directory
   - it ends up in `~/.dropbox-dist` (avoid installing the package `nautilus-dropbox` on a server, it'll give you another copy of dropbox in `/var/lib/dropbox` which gets confusing).
3. To control Dropbox from command line:

   - Download the command line control script [`dropbox.py`](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) (should also be linked to from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx))
   - Make it executable `chmod +x ~/Scripts/dropbox.py` and then make a symlink to it `sudo ln -s ~/Scripts/dropbox.py /usr/bin/dropbox`
   - Then you can control it with things like `dropbox status` see `dropbox help` for more
4. If you want Dropbox to auto-start on startup, follow a guide like [this](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment#Running_on_system_startup) to make a service script `/etc/init.d/dropbox`

Comment: I got this mostly/slightly working through just brute force, but this is basically what I needed to do, plus a few extra steps to get me the last mile. Perfect!

Comment: great, glad to hear it @dougoftheabaci! if there are common things that I missed off I'd be glad to hear them & potentially add to the list?

Comment: Nope, looks good to me. I didn't know the bit about the Nautilus package. Good thing I skipped that this time around.